# Help with filter formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So on Google Sheets, I have this:

`=iferror(FILTER('RAW DATA 2'!$B$2:$G,'RAW DATA 2'!$B$2:$B>=$B$1,'RAW DATA 2'!$B$2:$B<=$B$2),"")`,

The formula is working. However, I would like to skip a column from the range, my range goes from **B2:G**, and I would like to skip column **D** from the range, how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=iferror( 
  filter( 
    { 'RAW DATA 2'!B2:C, 'RAW DATA 2'!E2:G }, 
    B1 <= 'RAW DATA 2'!B2:B, 'RAW DATA 2'!B2:B <= B2 
  ) 
)
```